# A few matters on cgSceneGraph 1.4.2

Tags: html, canvas, rotation, keypress, nodes

I have a few questions about cgSceneGraph 1.4.2

**Nodes order**
I wonder if there is a way to change the indexing of the nodes inside a canvas. If we have more than one nodes, the order I create them is the order that these have in canvas, but this would be great if there was a way to change the order of them. These way a big node will not cover the previous nodes, preventing you to even access them.

Would a removal of all the nodes and redraw all of them in different order would make sense? Would this be not CPU-memory demanding?

Any other idea or solution for this?

**Keyboard key press**
Is there a way to lock the keyboard key press only inside canvas? For example we might have the canvas inside a page were a form might also exist. If we use the form to insert a few texts, then the key presses pass to the canvas too.

To catch the key pressing events I use

```
document.onkeydown = function (event) {
    scope.onKeyDown(event);
};
document.onkeyup = function (event) {
    scope.onKeyUp(event);
};
```

**Node Rotation**
Is there a way to rotate node in the same way a user resize/scale them? Maybe by using a key as qualifier to enable the rotation against resizing?

Sorry for all these questions. Thank you for your help and time.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 questions here :)

First one :
cgSceneGraph will render the nodes in the order they have been added.
So to change the z-index (there is no z-index on the framework) you have to use these 2 methods (that's what we use on our applications):

```
CGSGNode::detachChild  // will detach the child from its parent without destroy it. To destroy it, use "removeChild" instead
```

and

```
CGSGNode::addChild(childNode); // or "accChildAt(index)"
```

It's very fast so you can use it in real time.

Second one:
cgSceneGraph already catch keyboard events (mostly for multi selection).
If you want to override this you have to give a name to you handlers methods different than the ones used by the framework.

Third question:
that is not a "native" feature. It's always possible by extending the framework (which is very extensible) but it will be part of the v2 of the cgSceneGraph (development on the good way :)).
Rotation is already fully OK on the V1 of the framework, however the bounding box of the selected objects does not take care yet (in the v1) of the actual rotation.

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks you for your fast replies. 
About the first question and your answer. The way you describe here will give me the opportunity to move a node over an other, because it just recreate a node, so it puts over every other node. I am talking increasing or decreasing it's index by one, or if you like, a node could exchange it's index with the next one, in case of increasing, or the previous one in case of decreasing.

Comment: It does not recreate a node. With `detachChild` your node still exists but not connected to its parent anymore (no more connected to any node). Then you re-attach the node to the  same parent but at the end of the list (with `addChild`) or where you want in the list (with `addChildAt`). You can easily create a method that increase or decrease the current index of a node using these 2 methods. Actually it's a good idea, I'll add such a method in the v2 :)

Comment: Thank you for your help. You helped me to move my project on.

Comment: Glad to help :) If it's the correct answer, please mark it as is :)